# Variable containing data.table names changed in place?

Tags: r, data.table

Maybe some can tell me why the names I assigned to "idVars" are changing after adding a column to my data.table (without reassigning them)? How can I persist the assignment to store only the first two column names?

Thanks!

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(a=1:10, b=1:10)
idVars <- names(DT)
print(idVars)
# [1] "a" "b"

DT[, "c" := 1:10]
print(idVars)
# [1] "a" "b" "c"


# devtools::session_info()                
# data.table * 1.11.6  2018-09-19 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can create a `copy` of the `names` as the `names(DT)` and the 'idVars' have the same memory location

```
tracemem(names(DT))
#[1] "<0x7f9d74c99600>"
tracemem(idVars)
#[1] "<0x7f9d74c99600>"
```

So, instead create a `copy` of the `names`

```
idVars <- copy(names(DT))
tracemem(idVars)
#[1] "<0x7f9d7d2b97c8>"
```

and it wouldn't change after the assignment

```
DT[, "c" := 1:10]
idVars
#[1] "a" "b"
```

According to `?copy`:

> A `copy()` may be required when doing `dt_names = names(DT)`. Due to R's *copy-on-modify*, `dt_names` still points to the same location in memory as `names(DT)`. Therefore modifying `DT` *by reference* now, say by adding a new column, `dt_names` will also get updated. To avoid this, one has to *explicitly* copy: `dt_names <- copy(names(DT))`.

Comment: Great thanks! Was this behaviour changed lately? I'm wondering why I haven't stumbled over this earlier.

Comment: Big upvote for the explanation. Didn't know that R uses a pointer in that case.

Comment: @ismirsehregal  Not sure about the changes in this case, but usually when we do the `:=`, I create a copy of the initial object if I want to keep it separate